# Personal statement doesn't appear in developer story preview

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, developer-story

My personal statement
[image: personal statement]

does not appear anywhere on my developer story at `https://stackoverflow.com/story/<username>`.

I fee like it should be displayed in-between the reputation count and the "I want to work with" section, as it is also displayed in edit mode.

This is how it currently looks like:

[image: how it looks like]

I tested it with my adblock turned off, and on two different browsers.

Pretty sure this is not intentional, is it?

Comment: Well, your developer story is not public, maybe it's related, i.e. not a bug? Also, not sure where you expect to see the personal statement. All in all, I think you better clarify this bug report.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I switched it off to public but could still not see the personal statement. I will edit it to clarify it.

Comment: Mine shows up. Do you have "Only show your personal statement to employers" selected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My personal statement shows up exactly where you think it should be:

[image]

When you go edit, there is an option that says **Only show your personal statement to employers**. If you choose this, your statement will not show up in the preview.

[image]

Comment: Heh. That choice is really taking things a bit literally, isn't it? "Only show your personal statement to employers, not even to _you_" Did anyone expect it to mean this?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition well you do see it in edit mode / your dev story tab. It's when you go `https://stackoverflow.com/story/username` that you don't see it

Comment: That makes a bit more sense. OP said "preview" so I thought.... disclaimer: I don't use developer story (not really useful unless your work is public and on GitHub!)